What is a set called when it implements a distance function
Sorry, it's been a few years since I've looked into this stuff so my terminology may be off. Please bear with me.
When a set is ordered, the < operator is defined for that set. I can't think of an example, but my gut says that just because < is defined, that does not mean that - is defined.
Assuming what I said is true, what is it called when a set implements "distance" or "subtraction" or whatever you want to call it?
A set "closed over addition/subtraction" doesn't seem right to me. I'm thinking (again with my gut) that the function result does not have to be an element of the set.

A set with a notion of distance is called a metric space.
A metric space is a set $X$ and a metric function $d:X \times X \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ satisfying certain rules:

The distance from a point to itself is zero.
The distance between two distinct points is positive.
The distances from $x$ to $y$ and from $y$ to $x$ are the same.
The Triangle Inequality holds: $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. Intuitively, the distance from $x$ to $z$ is no larger than the distance making a stop at any intermediate point $y$.

